# How can I prevent java.util.Scanner from throwing NoSuchElementException when reading from System.in?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception, system.in

I'm attempting to ask the user for a double value, using Scanner.nextDouble(); but I'm getting a NoSuchElementException before I have a chance to type anything.  From what I can see in the documentation, this means that Scanner is at the end of the input.  However, I don't understand how that can happen when the Scanner is reading from System.in, not a file.

Is it possible that having other Scanners open is causing this?  I don't think that *should* be the case, as another method is successfully run before this code that opens and closes another Scanner.  But I don't really know enough about the ins and outs of Scanner (or much else!) to know if that is the issue.

Here's where I'm at currently, after a lot of failed attempts to re-write this code to get it working:

```
public static double collectDepositAmount(int accountNum){
    System.out.print("Enter how much you would like to deposit in Account #" + accountNum + ": $");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    double finalDeposit;
    try{
        double inputDeposit;
        inputDeposit = userInput.nextDouble();
```

There's more after that, but the exception always gets thrown at `userInput.nextDouble();`.  The `catch` block is only looking for InputMismatchException, and I close `userInput` right before I return a valid double.

Comment: This famous issue occurs when closing a `Scanner` instance created on `System.in` also closes `System.in` so the user input cannot be read afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Either you closed System.in, or, the next token isn't parsable as a double. It could be either issue; they'd both result in a `NoSuchElementException`.

### You closed `System.in`

Perhaps you closed it before ever calling this code (which doesn't close `System.in`, fortunately), which is easier than you might think. This will do it:

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
 // stuff here
}
```

After that try block is done, System.in is now closed (solution: Don't close `System.in`; don't close anything that you wrapped around `System.in` either).

### There's no double there

It could also simply be that the next token available **is not a double**, then you also get this exact same behaviour. To 'detect' that, call `.next()` instead, see if you do get something (and, what that is, for example by printing it). Could be that you're entering `5,20` and the system was expecting you to use dots for decimal separators (e.g. `5.20`) instead, thus concluding the next token isn't a double, and throwing that same exception.

Comment: So, closing a Scanner reading from System.in closes System.in itself?  Does this mean I should never close a Scanner that reads from System.in?

Comment: @IrishJet Yup. Never close those scanners. Unfortunately IDEs these days tend to ship with fairly extensive linting configured out of the box (linting = marking lines of code off as bad code style / dangerous) and they can mark that off as 'dangerous'. Ignore those linters; the java ecosystem as designed can't actually correctly determine when resources should be closed and when they should not. System.in being a fine example of that.